# Why MSDN recommends code organization that might produce "call of overloaded function is ambiguous"

Tags: c++, namespaces

I read some document from MSDN about structuring files like this
(I added tge link at the end)

## x.h

```
#ifndef _X_H
#define _X_H

namespace project{

int a();

}

#endif
```

## x.cc

```
#include "x.h"

using namespace project;

int a(){
    return 1;
}

int b(){
    return a();
}
```

When compiling this I get:

```
x.cc: In function ‘int b()’:
x.cc:10:11: error: call of overloaded ‘a()’ is ambiguous
  return a();
           ^
x.cc:5:5: note: candidate: int a()
 int a(){
     ^
In file included from x.cc:1:0:
x.h:6:5: note: candidate: int project::a()
 int a();
     ^
```

I know why this error happen and I know, how to fix it.

Question is why MSDN recommends this way or organizing source files?

## Update:

Here is the link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cb46ksf.aspx#Anchor_1

I agree they are doing it with class, instead of functions, but I guess class can produce similar error in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the .cc example is wrong. It should have either the same `namepace project { ... }` structure, or the definition there should be `int project::a`. Currently, the .cc file defines `int ::a()` in the global namespace.

Comment: and MSDN one is ok because of koenig lookup, because is class? with `int project::a()`, my example can produce normal .o file and this .o file can be linked correctly.

Comment: MSDN actually uses the equivalent of `int project::a`. Koenig lookup does not apply here.

Comment: `void ContosoDataServer::Foo()` is "ContosoDataServer" is the equivalent? Why they have "using namespace ContosoDataServer;"

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, that's the example's namespace name.